# consumption rate

Tags: fuel-consumption

I would like to know fuel consumption of the following vehicles per kilometer;-

- (1) Toyota Hilux
- (2) Toyota Land Cruiser
- (3) Nissan Navarra
- (4) Mitsubishi Canter.

If possible I would also like to know the fuel consumption per kilometer for the  different models of vehicle.

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific about the year and model of the vehicles in question, as they all have a selection of engines and trim levels that will effect the fuel consumption depending on your region.

Comment: Your best bet is to look at local car guides such as Parkers (in the UK).  The consumption will differ depending on engine size, model year, market variant (i.e. US spec, Jap spec, EU spec) and many many different things.  I'd say the vehicles listed are largely in the same class so would be roughly the same as each other.

Comment: Google for the year, make, model, and trim of your vehicle plus the words "fuel economy". You will generally always find the result. Example: ["2014 mitsubishi canter fe71 fuel economy"](https://www.google.com/search?q=2014+mitsubishi+canter+fe71+fuel+economy). First result: http://www.mitfuso.com/mitsubishi-fuso/Canter-Advantage/Fuel-Economy.

Comment: You can find this information on your own. SE isn't here to google for you.

Answer (score 2):

Your best choice would be [fuelly.com](http://www.fuelly.com/). It shows MPG (miles per gallon) units by default but you can switch that to whatever suits you best (for example L/100km). Here are the cars you were asking about:

1. [Toyota Hilux](http://www.fuelly.com/car/toyota/hilux)
2. [Toyota Land Cruiser](http://www.fuelly.com/car/toyota/land_cruiser)
3. [Nissan Navara](http://www.fuelly.com/car/nissan/navarra)
4. [Mitsubishi Canter](http://www.fuelly.com/car/mitsubishi/canter)

You can also use [fueleconomy.gov](https://www.fueleconomy.gov). But that's mostly for the US. It has pretty reliable results. It shows rate in MPG but you can change that in "personalize" section.

Here are some examples of the car models you were asking about:

1. [Toyota Land Cruiser](https://www.fueleconomy.gov/feg/noframes/35596.shtml)
2. [Nissan Frontier (aka. Navara)](https://www.fueleconomy.gov/feg/noframes/29525.shtml)
3. [Toyota 4Runner (similar to Hilux)](https://www.fueleconomy.gov/feg/noframes/29753.shtml)
4. Mitsubishi Canter - can't find it...

You can also take a look at some mobile apps, like for example [Fuelio: Gas log & costs](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kajda.fuelio&hl=en).

Comment: Note that if you take any MPG value from a US website, you need to know how many litres are in that particular type of Gallon for conversion (unless the site can do it for you). A US Gallon is 3.78541178 Litres, while an Imperial Gallon is 4.54609 Litres.